# finding the second minimum using an elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I cant get my head around composing the second minimum date using an Elasticsearch query.
the equivalent in SQL would be like this:

`SELECT name, MIN(date) AS date
  FROM index
 WHERE date> (SELECT MIN(date)
                 FROM index);`

Comment: `min` is an aggregation, so I'm not sure that's possible using elasticsearch's DSL. Would you consider sorting by date ascending, then taking the second record?

Comment: no because there are multiple records with the same value (which is also the minimum value) in the database

Comment: Then you can use a terms aggregation which will aggregate on distinct values. You can then use `"order": { "_key" : "asc" }` to sort ascending on those and take the 2nd one. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order